# Getting 400 Bad request error, While pulling data from AKamai Media analytics API to C#.net

Tags: c#

We are trying to pull information from Akamai media analytics API. We have a base URL and required tokens. We tried to authorize the user using below the code

```
GET /media-analytics/v1/audience-analytics/report-packs
Host: ********************.luna.akamaiapis.net
client_token:  ******* 
timestamp: ******
nonce: *********
```

But we are getting an error

> "title": "Bad request",
>       "status": 400,
>       "detail": "Authorization header missing"

Comment: You seem to have no Authorization header in your code. The error message suggests you need one. Can you clarify what your actual question is.

Comment: I have added the headers to the "HttpRequest". even after adding the headers it is giving "400" error

Comment: Did you sign the request as per the Akamai suggestion? https://github.com/akamai-open/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-C-Sharp. In java request auth headers are encoded with "Base64.encodeBase64String". So similarly, you can check it in C#. If have done it already, may be print the --verbose for your request, then that will be useful to debug further.